# curl --insecure not working

Tags: curl, ubuntu-20.04

I needed to run the below behind a proxy:

```
curl -L "https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash
```

Which returned errors related to SSL (because the proxy puts its cert in between).  I used '--insecure' and re-ran, which works up to a point, however - later in that install script, curl is called again, and returns the same SSL errors.

I added 'insecure' to ~/.curlrc so that the calling script would ignore the SSL errors.. however they still get thrown.. if I drop --insecure from the kick off it still works (validating .curlrc working).. so I figured it must be a permissions issue..

Ran 'chmod 666 .curlrc' and verified rw for all with 'ls -l' - same results..
How do I ignore these SSL errors?

Comment: Can you not trust the proxy at the OS level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are curling the script as yourself and then the script is running as root:

```
| sudo bash
```

When you pipe something into `sudo bash`, you are running bash as root, and bash will launch all subprocesses (including the `curl`s inside of the script) as root. Since root's account doesn't care about your `.curlrc`, it won't read it and won't apply your `--insecure`. You have a couple of options:

1. Download the script separately from running it and modify the lines containing `curl` (lines 137 and 182 at the time of writing)
2. Create a `.curlrc` file for root at `/root/.curlrc` with the contents `insecure`

Edit:

As an aside, it is not generally advised to have application-specific configuration files in your home directory be `o+wr`, because this would allow anyone with a login on the system to modify your personal configuration. You said that you ran `chmod 666 .curlrc` but this is inadvisable because then anyone on the system (assuming your home directory is `o+rx`) can modify your curl configuration, including setting a curl-specific socks proxy and them MiTM all of your curl traffic. This is especially dangerous because they could strip SSL and you wouldn't notice because you're already ignoring insecure connections for your own system proxy.

Comment: tysm!  marking as answer!